# Problem while using xampp 1.7.4

Tags: php, xampp

In my old system I was using xampp 1.7.1 with windows xp and developed one php project. It worked well. Now I install xampp 1.7.4. in another system and run the same project in this xampp.But it is not working properly.

Accessing undefined variable in php 5.2.9 is not showing any error(I used this previously).  But the same code (accessing undefined variable) does not works in php 5.3.4 (Now using). showing the 'undefined index' error

How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mostly 'undefined index'? You need to be more specific. Where is it finding the error?

Comment: <telepathy>in the old xampp you had error\notice reporting turned off and in this one you have it turned on</telepathy>

Comment: Not good but could work: `error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE)`

Comment: @Anbu Raj, wow. maybe i'd buy a crystall ball...

Answer (score 0):

In Php 5.3 you should declare/initialize all the variables used in the coding.